# AP Calculus Behavior

Tags: calculus, limits

Which of the following describes the behavior of $y=\sqrt[3]{x+2}$ at x = -2

a) Differentiable
b) Corner
c) Cusp
d) Vertical Tangent
e) Discontinuity

Which one is it and why? I know it is Vertical tangent, but how and why? Why isn't it the other ones?

Answer (score 2):

Simply apply the definition of all those terms to the function $y=\sqrt[3]{x+2}$ and see what works and what doesn't.

For instance, a function is differentiable at $x$ if $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ exists. In this case, does it?